# compatibility of Ubuntu 21.04 and Epson printer scanner XP-2100

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Would this cheap printer scanner Epson XP-2100 work with Ubuntu 21.04?

[Epson drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

Comment: Did you have any trouble finding drivers from the linked page? Did you have trouble installing the driver?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: We do not support hardware recommendations on Ask Ubuntu because they are opinion-based questions and cannot be answered definitively with facts and citations.  You are better off researching the manufacturer's documentation and reviews hosted by retailers and others who conglomerate product reviews.  Asking for a product review or recommendation on any kind of Q&A website or forum is only going to provide you with biased information from a poor sample size.

Comment: I simply expected an answer, yes or no, from somebody who tried.  This is a matter of fact, not opinion.

Comment: The Epson XP-2100 does not have an AirPrint facility. That's a fact. It will not work **OOTB** on 21.04. That's also a fact. Epson-provided drivers will be required. Another fact.